# Best way to create multiple variables for widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do some application that will use similar widgets, and here is how my Entry widgets creates:

```
        self.entries = []

    for number in range(10):
        name = "Group {}".format(number)
        self.entries.append((name, tkinter.Entry(self.parent, width=55, state= "readonly", readonlybackground= "#ccdeea")))
```

I've put widgets into list where each object in this list include Entry name and widget.

Question is how to make for each entry variable which this widget will use?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How would you specify the variable if you only had a single Widget?

Comment: matchedVariable = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entries.append(("Matched", tkinter.Entry(self.parent, width= 55, state= "disabled", disabledbackground="white", textvariable=matchedVariable)))
        matchedVariable.set("Setting new str")

Comment: Are you aware you don't need a variable for an entry widget? My advice: don't create the variables.

Comment: So what's keeping you from adding the variable to ``self.entries``, along with the name and Entry?  Or perhaps adding it to a different list, if that would be more convenient?

Comment: Ok, but how I can send string to widget without var in case when user will do some actions?

Comment: I'm not mind to put variable in exsisting self.entries list, bit how I can generate this variables first?

Comment: The entry widget has an `insert`, `delete`, and `get` method for setting, deleting, and retrieving the contents of the widget. These methods are all documented.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this methods, but can you please help me to find best way to achieve this with variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need names

You can create list with entries

```
self.entries = []

for _ in range(10):
    entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent, ...)
    self.entries.append(entry)
```

and later use

```
print( self.entries[0].get() )
print( self.entries[1].get() )
# ...
```

or

```
for x in range(10):
    print( self.entries[x].get() )
```

---

If you have to use `StringVar()` then you still don't need names

```
self.vars = []

for _ in range(10):
    var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Entry(self.parent, textvariable=var)
    self.vars.append(var)
```

and later use

```
print( self.vars[0].get() )
print( self.vars[1].get() )
# ...
```

or

```
for x in range(10):
    print( self.vars[x].get() )
```

---

If you really need some names the use dictionary

```
self.entries = {}

for x in range(10):
    self.entries['Group {}'.format(x)] = tkinter.Entry(self.parent, ...)
```

and later you can use

```
self.entries['Group 0'].get()
self.entries['Group 1'].get()
# ...
```

but to use `for` you will need again `format()`

```
for x in range(10):
    print( self.entries['Group {}'.format(x)].get() )
```

which makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, now its clear. Names are used just to make code more readable by user because list contain human readable name.