# Creating and configuring multiple labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list with some data, that changes:

```
list=[]

if len(list) < 5:
    list.append(data)
else:
    list.pop(0)
    list.append(data)
```

removing first item and adding new.

**I want tk labels to behave like that list when I click a button:**

```
for i, pk in enumerate(list):
    lab = tk.Label(text=pk)
    lab.grid(row=0, column=i)
```

It kinda works, but there is a problem. It does not change text in labels it just puts new labels above, so it starts lagging after a while. I tried config but it just overwrites last label.

Then I decided to create multiple labels:

```
labnames = []

for i in range(5):
    labnames.append('lab' + str(i))

for i, name in enumerate(labnames):
    name = tk.Label()
```

but it doesn't let me do anything with them later. I could manually create every label, but I'm gonna need a lot of them, there must be a smart way to do that. So how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in type name.

Comment: That name here is just for simplicity. It isnt called like that in actual code.

Comment: Why don't you use `labnames` to store the created labels instead of just the text of the labels?

Comment: this 'labnames' list looks like [lab0, lab1, lab2...] then I want to create labels with names from that list. I dont understand how I can store actual labels in list so I can change them later with config

Comment: `name` will be overwritten in each iteration of the loop and so it is useless.

Comment: Then how do I create like for example 100 variables and assign a label to each of them. And more importantly how I should get needed label from them, cause I cant use indexex like in list

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. So it is better to provide a [mre] and the problem you came across.

Comment: I want to be able to config labels, not just putting new ones above. For that I need a lot of label variables like: lab0 = tk.Label(bla bla) ; lab1 = tk.Label(bla bla) e ; lab2 = tk.Label(bla bla). I could easily solve this problem if I needed like 5 labels or so, but I need a bit more, and don't want just brainless ctrl+c ctrl+v. So Is there a way to make a lot of these lab-x and then somehow access them by their id?

Comment: I found the answer. You were right but somehow I misunderstood what you meant there. I thought you can't make a list of tk labels. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
self.labnames = []
for n in range(5):
     lab = tk.Label(self.downframe)
     self.labnames.append(lab)
```

Perfectly works for my needs

[More examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418237/best-way-to-create-multiple-variables-for-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

Much better like this.

```
self.labnames = [lab for n in range(5)]
lab = tk.Label(self.downframe)
```